# URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login

I have filled everything in Settings > Advanced > Client OAuth Settings, my only problem is that I do not have SSL on my website, hence I get this error. So instead of using my website url I have used a website URL which has SSL (https://housing.com/) in the Valid OAuth redirect URIs field, but I still get the error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more concise and included the previous title in the question body. Please edit in to provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try entering also (https://www.housing.com/) in the whitelisted websites